# MFC change CListCtrl background color

Tags: c++, background, mfc, listbox, clistctrl

I am trying to develop an MFC application. I have a `CListCtrl` object and I want to change it's background color completely. I tried to make it in
`HBRUSH OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)` event. But this event isn't fired for `CListCtrl`object. So How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You may use CListCtrl::SetBkColor.

For list views you also can use owner draw (DrawItem) or custom draw.

Custom draw is the easiest way for getting more control over the background. Setting the colors only is really simple.

In CodeGuru you find a good class and description that simplifies the use of custom draw.
[Part I](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/listview/customdrawing/article.php/c4195/Custom-Draw-ListView-Controls-Part-I.htm), [Part II](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/listview/customdrawing/article.php/c4199/Custom-Draw-ListView-Controls-Part-II.htm)

Answer (score 2):

According to the MSDN documentation, you can invoke the [`CListCtrl::SetBkColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/fe08a1ca-4b05-4ff7-a12a-ee4c765a2197.aspx#clistctrl__setbkcolor) method to set the background color of a `CListCtrl`.

For finer grained control, you may want to read [this CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12343/Alternate-Row-Colors-for-the-CListCtrl), that shows how to use the custom draw feature of the listview control to draw rows with alternate colors.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the properties in Owner Draw true for background color of any control property[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRh8X.png)
then using OnCtlColor method or Using setBkColor(RGB(...)); it will be working..